# How risky is this xss exposure and how to make it safer

Tags: php, xss

Before describing the problem, I will give you the context why I am allowing this xss exposure.

**Context**

I rely on an external API. One of the fields returned by the API is html (already encoded). I can decode it and show it in the page without worrying because they have no interest in introducing malicious code. The problem that I found is that their html is not always valid and it breaks the page if shown as it is. So now I am showing it on an iframe so that it does not break anything.

**Code**

I have the html encoded string in a hidden textarea in the main page that embeds an iframe like this:

```
<textarea id="my-data" class="hidden">
<?php echo $mydata;?>
</textarea>
<div> 
<iframe src="/iframepage" frameborder="0" style="padding:0;width:100%;height:400px;">
</iframe>
```

And in my iframe page I have this html:

```
<div id="my-data">
</div>
```

And this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#my-data', window.parent.document).length){
        $parentJobDescription = $('#my-data', window.parent.document);
        $('#my-data').html($parentJobDescription.val());
    }

});
```

**Problem Description & Questions**

1. What kind of risk I am incurring if somebody embeds the iframe page in an page that contains malicious code in a field with id "my-data"?
2. I checked for the existing ways of preventing that page from being embedded in a page other than my own website. I found that there are some tags that you can use to tell the browser not to do so, and also some js code that you can use to prevent that. Both methods are not very reliable. In the back-end you can configure a .htaccess to prevent pages from being embedded in external pages. But it seems that it does that for all pages not a specific page. Is there still any possibility to make this secure?

Comment: In the `$('#my-data').html(..)` they can put also `<script>` tags. Thus they can run javascript in your domain in the name of the user. Thus they can make any serverside call as it was made by the authenticated user

Comment: If their code is "not always valid", then that's a good enough reason for me not to trust them at all. You know, maybe their security is also "not always valid".

Comment: *because they have no interest in introducing malicious code* perhaps they don't, but someone who has hacked into their system may well have an interest in this....

Comment: @Siguza, makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it secure, don't do anything in the parent, delete the textbox and move everything to the iframe page:

```
<div id="my-data">

  <?php echo $myData; ?>

</div>
```

... wherever you get `$myData` from, needs to be put here as well.

Comment: I know I can do that. It gonna cost me an additional call to their API to fetch the same data because in their terms of service they do not allow to cache or store their results. I will wait to see if somebody have a solution. If not I will accept your answer.

Comment: Putting the stuff in to a textarea is as well caching as putting it in to a session variable. And I assume that the legal term "caching" does not include "keep it for some milliseconds until the other page opens" ...

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of risk I am incurring if somebody embeds the iframe page in
>   an page that contains malicious code in a field with id "my-data"?

Outputting the

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

response header will prevent your framed page from being framed by anyone else ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)).

Even if they did frame your response, a malicious site would not be able to read the content due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

However, due to attacks like Clickjacking, it is best practice to output this header anyway.

Also note that `X-Frame-Options` is currently being phased out in favour of [CSP's frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#frame-ancestors), so for the time being it would be useful to output both headers for old and new browser support.

Comment: I already modified it and i am using data from the backend session as suggested by the other post. But your point is very relevant  and I will definitely add that to the framed page. Thanks again.